# Laravel 4: Working with relationships in seeds

Tags: database, many-to-many, laravel, laravel-4

Is there an easy way to manage many-to-many relationships in the new seeds feature of L4?

One way would be to make a seed for the pivot table, but I would be a lot of work.

Any thoughts on a good workflow for this sort of thing?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In the latest version of Laravel 4 you define the order that all the seeder scripts are run in the "run" method of the DatabaseSeeder class.

```
public function run()
{
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;');

    $this->call('PrimaryTableOneSeeder');
    $this->command->info('The first primary table has been seeded!');

    $this->call('PrimaryTableTwoSeeder');
    $this->command->info('The second primary table has been seeded!');

    $this->call('PivotTableSeeder');
    $this->command->info('The pivot table has been seeded!');

    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;');
}
```

You'll notice that I disable the foreign key constraints before and after running all my seeding. This may be bad practice but it's the only way I can use the truncate function to re-set the id count for each table. If you follow the guide on [inserting related models](http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#inserting-related-models) this practice may be unnecessary.

```
class PrimaryTableOneSeeder extends Seeder {

public function run()
{
    DB::table('primaryone')->truncate();
    Primaryone::create(array(
        'field' => 'value',
        'created_at' => new DateTime,
        'updated_at' => new DateTime
    ));
}
```

To use [mass assignment](http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment) as I'm doing in my example and as the latest version of the documentation does, you'll need to specify either some guarded or fillable columns for the model. To do this simply add property to your model like this:

```
class Primaryone extends Eloquent {

protected $guarded = array('id');
```

Comment: I would say this is almost the right answer. If I were you I would not disable foreign key checks. 

It can be discussed wether it is good to truncate the tables as well. I would not do it, but that is just me. The reason is that db:seed can be run at anytime meaning that the db could have important data in it.

Comment: @AndHeiberg That is a good point. Everyone is not aware that seeds are not intended for use in production but rather for seeding a development database with test data which is ok if it gets truncated. Data for production should be added either through the applications own interface or via a ssh db connection.

Comment: Is there an sqlite-compatible method? `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` triggers an error with sqlite. This is where my issue originates: I've been working with a quickie sqlite db for dev and am now trying to shift over to postgres, only to find out that sqlite's leniency hid a number of problems.

Comment: @CJThompson - Sorry for the way late reply. My solution for sqlite is to completely destroy/recreate the database. For unit testing I have an empty sqlite database and a fully seeded database which I clone before testing.

Comment: How about PostgreSQL solution? SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS also triggers an error in PostgreSQL.

Comment: @isimmons if seeds are only for the development what is the official way to put data that is not generated but needs to be there like list of countries and related states in production  and how to updated them.

Answer (score 3):

Laravel seed files are regular PHP scripts (except they need to return an array). You can query the database in seed files (using Eloquent, Fluent builder or even PDO).

One way to tackle the many-to-many problem is to deliberately name your seed files so that the pivot table is populated last... For example, you could prepend a numeric value to the file name (i.e.  1_authors.php, 2_books.php, 3_authors_books.php etc.). Artisan sorts the filenames alphabetically before executing them.

I have posted a small tutorial on **[Laravel 4 database seeding](http://laravelbook.com/laravel-database-seeding/)** - this should get you going. Additionally, you may consult the official doc on [seeding](http://doc.laravelbook.com/migrations/).

Answer (score 0):

Seeding is for simple information, test data and static information. I wouldn't recommend using it to handle relationships. Personally, I only use it for 2 or 3 record per table, to help test my application.

When developing your application, think about working on the data entry (admin) area first then the front end. That way you can easily add test data.

Comment: I would agree, but even when you have easy data entry seeding is still important and helpful. So unless you have some way of converting the admin input into seeds is this really answering my question?