# How write seeder in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7, laravel-seeding

I have table taggable, it's table for Many To Many Polymorphic Relations (Tag and post):

```
taggable_id - id of Post
tag_id - id of Tag
taggable type - location of post model (default value"App/Models/Posts/Post")
is_search_term - boolen (0 or 1)
```

How create a seeder which each time create same records for relations?

Comment: This may helps though it's laravel4 [Laravel 4: Working with relationships in seeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666277/laravel-4-working-with-relationships-in-seeds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tag_id will be created by db automatically if it is set to primary key, taggable_id you get values from Tag model.

You can try something like this;

```
$factory->define(App\Tag::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'taggable_id' => random_int(\DB::table('posts')->min('id'), \DB::table('posts')->max('id')),
        'is_search_term'=>$faker->numberBetween(0,1),
'taggable_type'=>$faker->sentence(2),

    ];
});
```

Comment: But when i start new seeding it was new relations post with tags.

Comment: what do you mean??

Comment: All time when i start seeding relationship must be same (fields in table must be same, but not random)

Comment: For exampler, post with id 1, always must has tag with id 1 and id2

Comment: initialize Post and create a post seeder aswell; $post = new Post; then refrenece relationship 'taggable_id'=> $post->tags->id